# How to open a material design dialog from the code (.xaml.cs)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design

i'm coding a wpf application using material design

i've a `DialogHost`named dialog and i want to open and show its content from the code (.xaml.cs), in XAML the command is `Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}"`
but i sought in DialogHost properties and methods and i didn't find anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs#dialoghostshow

`var result = await DialogHost.Show(view, "RootDialog", ClosingEventHandler);`

If you'd like a concrete example, check out the demo source:

https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/2740f14a814896d42032ae0013b765a8a0ec04c3/MainDemo.Wpf/Domain/DialogsViewModel.cs#L36

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use this :

```
view.IsOpen = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a Name to your DialogHost like: `<materialDesign:DialogHost x:Name="MyDialogHost">`.

And then in your XAML.CS file you can use the `MyDialogHost.ShowDialog(...)` method to show its content like:

```cs
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      MyDialogHost.ShowDialog(MyDialogHost.DialogContent);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your ViewModel where you host a Dialog, you can simply add these lines:

```
var dialog = DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand;
dialog.Execute(null, null);
```